# Update database using MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

There are no errors shown when I click the register button to register new users, but the data isn't inserted in the database.

```
<?php
    session_start();
     if(isset($_POST['name'])&&isset($_POST['password'])){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    $link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
    $select=mysqli_select_db($link,'first_db');
    $name=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$name);
    $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$password);
    $query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$name'";
    $run=mysqli_query($link,$query);    
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($run);

    if ($count>0) {
    echo 'Sorry! This Username already exists!';
    } else {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, password)
                VALUES
                ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[password]')";
    }
     }
    else{
        echo"Cannot be blank";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Save `$_POST[name]` to a variable first, `$name = $_POST[name]` and  
`$password = $_POST[password]`. Then put it inside your sql statement. Like, `$sql = "..... values ('$name', '$password')";`

Comment: Thank you  Erfan Ahmed Emon  it worked

Comment: @user9053914 Use Prepared Queries to enhance your security.

Comment: Don't use the deprecated and insecure **mysql*-functions**. They have been **deprecated** since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. You are wide open to **[SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your else part you just created the query need to execute it

```
if ($count>0)
{
   echo 'Sorry! This Username already exists!';
} 
else
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, password)VALUES('$name','$password')";
    $run=mysqli_query($link,$sql);// add this statement then your record inserted



}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to execute your Insert query like below :

```
mysqli_query($link,$sql);
```

But you have to use **Prepared Insert Query** to make it more secure:

```
// prepare and bind User Query
$queryUsers = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO 
users(name,password) VALUES (?, ?)");
$queryUsers->bind_param("ss",$name,$password);

$name = $_POST[name];
$password = $_POST[password];

// execute Users Query
$queryUsers->execute();

// Close Connections
$queryUsers->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to execute the query string like you did to check whether the user already exists or not.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, password)
            VALUES
            ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[password]')";
$run=mysqli_query($link,$sql);    // Executing the query here.
```